# Docker - Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device (GCP Service Account)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, service-accounts

The command `docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < ~/service-account.json` works locally, but when I try to run it in a CI environment like Github Actions, I get the following error.

> Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
>
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 3):

The `oauth2accesstoken` authentication strategy worked for me.

1. Login to `gcloud` cli using service account

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${HOME}/service-account.json`

2. Print access token and use it to log into docker

`gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://gcr.io`

Comment: This will not be using the service account for the access token.  You need to use `gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account <service-account>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are impersonating a service account with an authentication token to login docker. You can obtain an access token for the service account. Since the token is short-lived, request it less than an hour before you use it to connect with the Container Registry.

The steps are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#token).

Comment: This question is not about roles assigned to a service account. It's about how to login to docker using a service account in a non-TTY environment.

Comment: Good to know that, you found the solution. I have edited my answer as well.